# How to extract columns which contains lots of 0 value with R?

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix with lots of columns (more than 817.000) and 40 rows . I would like to extract the columns which contain lots of 0 (for example > 30 or 35 , no matter the number) .

That should extract several columns, and I will choose one randomnly which I will use as a reference for the rest of the matrix.

Any idea?

Edit :

```
              OTU0001 OTU0004 OTU0014 OTU0016 OTU0017 OTU0027 OTU0029 OTU0030
Sample_10.rare       0       0      85       0       0       0       0       0
Sample_11.rare       0      42     169       0      42     127       0      85
Sample_12.rare       0       0       0       0       0       0       0      42
Sample_13.rare     762     550    2159     127     550       0     677    1397
Sample_14.rare     847     508    2751     169    1397     169     593    1990
Sample_15.rare    1143     593    3725     677    2116     466     212    2286
Sample_16.rare    5630    5291    5291    1270    3852    1185     296    2836
```

It should extract 4 columns, `OTU0001 OTU0016  OTU0027 OTU0029` because they got 3 zero each. And if it is possible, I would like to extract the position of the extracted columns.

Comment: You can use `colSums(df == 0)` to find how many 0 entries there are, and simply filter. Did you try anything? Can we see an attempt?

Comment: So for your example something like `mat[,colSums(mat == 0) >= 3]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option with `base R`

```
Filter(function(x) sum(x == 0) > 7, df)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this (Where 7 is the number of relevant zeros):

```
library(dplyr)
df <- tibble(Col1 = c(rep(0, 10), rep(1, 10)),
                     Col2 = c(rep(0,5), rep(1, 15)),
                     Col3 = c(rep(0,15), rep(1, 5)))

y <- df %>% 
      select_if(function(col) length(which(col==0)) > 7)
```

Comment: FYI, OP says they have a matrix, not a data frame/tibble